# Undirected Graph Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that an undirected graph with all vertices of degree greater than or equal to two must contain a circuit.

I have no idea how to approach this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you prove that number of edges greater than or equal to number of vertices implies there's a cycle?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Start at a vertex $v_0$ and walk along the edges until either you come back to a vertex that you already visited, or you reach a dead end. In the first case you’ve made a circuit. In the second you’ve reached a vertex of degree ... what?

Comment: I get 2, but i need a formal-ish proof

Comment: @thebottle394: No, if you reach a dead end, you’ve reached a vertex of degree $1$. Such a vertex doesn’t exist in your graph, so you can never reach a dead end. That means that your path must at some point repeat a vertex $v$, and the part of it from $v$ back around to $v$ is a circuit.

Comment: I do not see how Brian Scott's proof is valid...Just because I can reach a vertex I have already visited does not imply that I have traversed to ALL the vertices in the graph...Do you mean to say I must visit all vertices at least once before returning to vertex I've already visited? And even then, how do I know there exists an edge between the last vertex I end up and vertex I started at?

Comment: @M0RF3US: The question has nothing to do with visiting all vertices of the graph. You might in fact have made a circuit of just three vertices in a graph with $300$ vertices. The theorem says that there is a circuit, not that there is a Hamilton circuit.

Answer (score 1):

A tree has a maximum number of edges (n-1) where n is the number of vertices.  If all vertices have degree greater than or equal to 2, then the total number of edges = $\frac{1}{2}\sum (d_i) >= n$.

Comment: I have not learned that formula yet, so I can't use that

Comment: Look at Brian Scott's proof as it's neater than mine.  The formula that the $\sum d_i = 2 e$ is not something you need to have learned, it just says that every edge contributes 1 to the degree for each vertex it contains.

Answer (score 0):

For each nonempty Graph $G$ consider $(|V|,|E|) \in
\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, where $V$ is its set of vertices and $E$ is its set of edges.
The lexicographic order on $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is a well-order,
so you can do a proof by induction on $(|V|,|E|)$.

Suppose $G$ is a minimal counterexample. Then certainly $(3,3) < (|V|,|E|)$.

If all vertices of $G$ have degree $>2$ then delete an edge and
obtain a graph of type $(|V|,|E|-1)$ in which you will have a circuit.

If $G$ has a vertex of degree 2, then delete that vertex and connect its
two neighbours with a new edge, obtaining a graph of type $(|V|-1,|E|-1)$,
in which you will have a circuit; if that circuit does not involve the new
edge, all ist fine, otherwise replace the new edge by the deleted path of
length 2.